# How to close the autocompelte with gray background in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete

[image]

As the image above, the `pregs` is a list and while I pressed `appe` and select the first intellesense (`append`), not only vscode will auto-complete the `append` but also `x`, but the `x` is completely **useless** for me and it will block the rest auto-complete in quote. Anyway to close this feature ? Thanks.

Comment: Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.